# Will the Ionic View app only load pages from an ionic directory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, trigger.io, ionic-view

I'm using the ionic and Trigger.io frameworks. To test on my device I'm using the ionic view app, which works fine when I'm loading a sample page from the www folder in the ionic directory, but I want to load the index from Trigger.io's main directory. 
How can I configure the ionic view app to load from the directory I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can change directory with documentRoot in your ionic.config.json file. In this example, rename the project app folder 'www' to 'app'.

```
{
  "name": "SmoothRiders",
   "gulpStartupTasks": [
    "watch"
  ],
  "documentRoot": "app",
  "createDocumentRoot": "app",
  "watchPatterns": [
    "app/js/*",
    "!app/css/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Refer [this ionic page](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/blob/master/README.md#serving-an-alternate-document-root)

Comment: There is no ionic.project file only ionic.config.json. in that file there is a "name" and "app id" property so I tried to add the document root and CreateDocumentRoot properties like in the example but that didn't work. I'll give the bounty to you anyway however if no one else answers by the time it runs out.

Comment: Thanks Spilot. The new name of ionic.project file is ionic.config.json. I hope it works for you.